# Tkinter icon configuration error with Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, icons

I try to change the ugly Tkinter logo, at top left, follow the documentation, however I get error.
Probably is trivial trouble or related with Python version, mine is 2.7.

But the interesting thing is if you run first without change icon, and after run the script bellow it change without trouble, however if you run the script at first time give the follow error:

TclError: bitmap "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\DLLs\sca.ico" not defined

My script:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.iconbitmap(r'C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\DLLs\sca.ico')
root.mainloop()
```

My new icon is in this path: C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\DLLs\sca.ico'

Comment: the " root.mainloop() " is in the next line

Comment: please share a link to that icon if possible

Answer (score 0):

Change `root.iconbitmap(C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\DLLs\sca.ico)` to `root.wm_iconbitmap(C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\DLLs\sca.ico)` and it might work.

Comment: thanks,  but don't change the behavior,,the trouble continues.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use string as parameter:

```
root.iconbitmap(r'C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\DLLs\sca.ico')
```

If you get error `_tkinter.TclError: error reading bitmap file`  use XBM format instead of ICO.

For Linux (worked for me) you need add also '@' at the begin of string:

```
app_icon = '/home/user/icons/number-three_66512.XBM'
root.iconbitmap('@' + app_icon)
```